# Initial View Controller Not Appearing

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I'm building a map app. The initial view controller says get started (GetStartedVC), which leads you to the next view controller so you can choose a place (PlaceVC), which then leads to a programmatic GoogleMap mapView (GoogleMapInterfaceVC). I have `GetStartedVC` set as my initial view controller upon launch. However, whenever I build and run the app, `GoogleMapInterfaceVC` is the initial view controller. I am concerned this problem is caused by my launch code in `AppDelegate.swift`? Here is the code :

```
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("APIkey")
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("APIkey")

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    if let window = self.window {
        window.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        window.accessibilityIdentifier = "GoogleMapInterfaceVC"

        let nav = UINavigationController()
        let mainView = GoogleMapInterfaceVC()
        nav.viewControllers = [mainView]
        window.rootViewController = nav
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Is this the issue?

Comment: For clarification: When I delete this AppDelegate.swift code, my GetStartedVC becomes the new initial ViewController. However I am then unable to access the map from PlacesVC. This is why I'm concerned I'm writing the AppDelegate.swift launch code wrong and why it's the cause of my problem.

Comment: Also for clarification: The code above is placed in this function: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

Answer (score 0):

I know its been over a year.  I'm surprised no one posted an answer.  Did you ever solve this?

In the code snippet above you are placing a Navigation Controller as the root view controller and in the Nav Controller you are placing only the GoogleMapInterfaceVC.  You should change this to the GetStartedVC like this.

```
let nav = UINavigationController()
    let mainView = GetStartedVC()
    nav.viewControllers = [mainView]
    window.rootViewController = nav
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Then, when the user does the appropriate action to choose a Place you do this

```
{
    navigationController.pushViewController(placeVC, animation: true)
}
```

and when the user selects the Map action

```
{
   navigationController.pushViewController(googleMapInterfaceVC, animation:true)
}
```

You should get the back button and pop view controller for free.